# Transit visa through Beijing to Macau

Tags: visas, transit, beijing, russian-citizens, macau

I have Russian citizenship and going to travel to **Macau**.

My flight will be transit through **Beijing**. I know that I can get a transit visa for 72 hours in the airport of Beijing, but only if I follow to the third country.

Is Macau a third country? Or is it just area of China?

Will I be able to get a transit visa on arrival in Beijing?

Comment: Not pertinent on the date of the question, but for whoever is interested in 2018, the 72 hours has been changed to 144 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macau is a [Special Administrative Region](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Administrative_Region_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China) and has it's own government, own rules, own passports and a [separate visa policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Macau). Keeping that in mind you would have to obtain a separate visa in Macau.

Transiting through Beijing Airport will not be a problem as you mentioned (with the 72 hour rule which is valid for Russian citizens). Since the border control between China and Macau is well defined, Macau for all practical purposes can be considered a separate country.

This can be confirmed (albeit vaguely) from the fact that many sources ([China Southern](http://www.csair.com/en/news/2013/20130724.shtml)), mention a third country or region.

> Foreign nationals with valid international traveling documents and air ticket for a connecting flight with confirmed date of flight and seat for a third country (region) leaving China at Guangzhou Baiyun International Airport within 72 hours

In this case Macau SAR will be counted as a separate region and a visa for there will be valid for the transit thru Beijing.

Comment: You seem to be talking about visas to Macau, but the OP is asking about transit visas through Beijing.

Comment: @Flimzy Whoops. I misinterpreted the question. Updating...